# Converted lines to one feature using Dissolve but exports as multiple features

Tags: qgis, vector, export, svg, inkscape

In QGIS, I've taken all of my lines/features and "dissolved" them into one feature, but after exporting as a SVG or PDF, it imports into Inkscape as 1231 features (the amount I originally had before dissolving the lines in QGIS). Is there a way to keep it as one feature when exporting?

When exporting from the New Page Layout, I've selected "Always export as vectors" and "Export map layers as SVG Groups" and still no difference.